# Boolean IF wont go through even when values are good

Tags: c++, arduino, boolean, boolean-logic

I am quite new in C++ but this is absurd. I don't understand why this won't go through: [image]

On your left hand side you can see if statement: `if((p.x >= 320) == (p.x <= 400))` on your right hand side you can see values (from debugging process). As you can see when `p.x = 360` that is both `higher than 320` and `lower from 400` so both makes `true` and there are equal on `both sides`, program wont go through that `if` statement. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I can see:

```
Serial.print(p.x,OCT);
```

OCT means octal, which means you are printing `p.x` in octal. If `p.x` is 360 in octal, it means it is 240 in decimal :/

Rewrite the debug code - make DEC from both OCT, you'll see the right numbers.

Comment: For God sake man! You are true hero here! Insomnia got me! :/

Comment: This is a classic mistake, you can try to solve it for ages without success :D @Slay29